# GitHub Actions ignoring pull_request.closed

Tags: github, github-actions

I've created a simple workflow for some experimentation:

```
name: workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - release/**
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - reopened
      - synchronize
      - edited
      - closed
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - ".github/workflows/workflow.yml"
      - "**"
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs: {}

jobs:
  diag:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - shell: bash
        name: diag
        run: |
          echo ${{ github.ref }}
          echo ${{ github.event_name }}
          echo ${{ github.event.action }} 
          echo ${{ github.event.pull_request.merged }}
```

I've created `release/*` branches multiple times, commited & pushed changes, performed a PR process, closed and merged the pull requests.

The workflow appears to be only firing on the `push` event only, yielding the following output:

```
> Run echo refs/heads/main
  echo refs/heads/main
  echo push
  echo  
  echo 
  shell: /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
refs/heads/main
push
```

Despite closing the PR(s) I haven't had the `pull_request.closed` event fire once. Is it normal for `push` to override this event? I don't think I've seen this mentioned in the docs - or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Since all triggers are "or" (meaning specifying more than one triggers the workflow multiple times), I'd start by removing all unrelated triggers and see if it triggers with only the `closed` type on `pull_request`.